# Regular expression for Norwegian numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regular expression that is going to match all phone numbers in Norway. That means that number can begin with +47, 0047, 47 or without  country code. To achieve that I am using following regular expreession:

```
Pattern.compile("^((0047)?|(\"+47)?|(47)?)\"d{8}$")
```

The problem is that it is never matched. I am testing it on the following valid examples:

```
90909090,   normal number
4790909090, number with country code
+4790909090, country code using +
004790909090, country code using 00
```

and invalid:

```
+47909090, without country code or too short number
9090909o,  invalid character
9090909,  too few digits
+4690909090, wrong country code
909090909, too many digits
00474790909090 Trying to fool the regex now
```

Comment: Do you really have `/` at the end? It cannot follow the end of string. Try `^(?:[+]?(?:00)?47)?[0-9]{8}$`.

Comment: Do you really want the `\"`s in the middle? There are no double quotes in your examples.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that just because standard Norwegian telephone numbers are 8 digits today, that doesn't mean they will like that forever. Or even for long. Plus there are some non-standard numbers even today that are valid telephone numbers that don't match your desired pattern  - see http://eng.nkom.no/market/numbering/e.164-numbering-plan/general-norwegian-numbering-plan-for-telephony-etc.e.164

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think you're looking for

```
(0047|\+47|47)?\d{8}
```

which in your Java expression would be:

```
Pattern.compile("(0047|\\+47|47)?\\d{8}");
```

Comment: Then to match the entire string against the pattern you use [Matcher#matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches\(\)) rather than Matcher#find, as that would find occurrences anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Sami's answer is nearly correct, but would not be able to identify numbers starting with 0 or 1. Numbers starting with 0 is not allowed and numbers starting with 1 are reserved in Norway ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Norway)). The following should work:

```
/^(0047|\+47|47)?[2-9]\d{7}$/
```

In your Java expression:

```
Pattern.compile("^(0047|\+47|47)?[2-9]\d{7}$")
```